# list comprehension to create list of list

Tags: python

What is the list comprehension to achieve this:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[[x,False] for x in a]
```

will give,

```
[[1,False],[2,False],[3,False],[4,False],[5,False]]
```

How can I get True for some number in the list? I need something like this:

```
[[1,False],[2,False],[3,False],[4,True],[5,False]]
```

My random playing has not solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `if-else` conditional:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [[x, True if x == 4 else False] for x in a]
>>> b
[[1, False], [2, False], [3, False], [4, True], [5, False]]
```

or just:

```
>>> b = [[x, x == 4] for x in a]
```

Comment: Why not just `[[x, x!=4] for x in a]` ?

Comment: @ValentinCLEMENT, that's `==` not `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = [[x, x==4] for x in a]
>>> b
[[1, False], [2, False], [3, False], [4, True], [5, False]]
>>>
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `x==4` will return `True` if x is equal to 4; otherwise, it will return `False`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?

```
b=[[x, x==4] for x in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ternary operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to choose different values based on conditions:

```
conditional_expression ::=  or_test ["if" or_test "else" expression]
```

**Example:**

```
>>> [[x,False if x%4 else True] for x in a]
[[1, False], [2, False], [3, False], [4, True], [5, False]]
```

Comment: Your example would be better ´[[x, x%4 == 0] for x in a]´

Comment: @UdoKlein IMO the question is more about how to add condition in that list comprehension. So, that's what I tried to show.

Comment: Of course. However you also show mapping boolean TRUE to TRUE and FALSE to FALSE by means of the ternary operator. IMHO this is bad practice.